# Stack overflow in c# app using c++ dll

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli, stack-overflow

I've got a c# program which is using a c++/cli managed dll. The dll contains a lot of legacy code, consisting of quite a few win32 windows.

Problem is, the windows in the dll need a bit more stackspace than average *cough*. Since these are not background processes but win32 api I need to enlarge the stack size of the GUI thread (at least I think the win32 api in the dll will use the main gui process).

So I need a way to enlarge the size of the GUI thread in a c# process.

Since I found no settings to achieve this I tried editbin /STACK from the command line, which works. Problem is, it only works in the command line, if I try to enter it as post-build-step for some reason the stack size of the binary does not change, even though the postbuild step is properly executed and throws no error :(

```
editbin.exe /STACK:2097152 $(TargetPath)
```

(Editbin.exe is in the path, and there is no error in the output window)

So how do I get more stack size for my c++ dll?

[Update]

I noticed a problem using editbin.exe.

This does not work, neither in command line nor as post build step:

```
editbin.exe /STACK:2097152 c:\some\path\bin\release\app.exe
```

This does work in command line, but not as build step:

```
editbin.exe /STACK:2097152 app.exe
```

But I need it to work as post build step. I tried to put it into a batch file, echo'd to make sure call and working dir are ok, but still it does not work. Strange.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your command with a batch file? That'd make it more command-line-ish, so maybe it does the trick.

Comment: Can you also post your Post-Build-Macro to do so? Maybe we can find the error there.

Comment: herenvardo, I tried to put it in a cmd, to no avail :(

Comment: @Bobby, posted the post build step.

Comment: @Sam: Should work in my opinion...are there any spaces in the path? Like `editbin.exe /STACK:2097152 "$(TargetPath)"`?

Comment: @Bobby, no spaces in the path, and I tried both ways to no avail. I even echo'd the parameter in the batch script back to me to make sure it's the right file :(

Comment: Arg, found a problem:
Editbin /Stack... c:\whatever\myapp.exe does not work.
Editbin /stack... myapp.exe does work.
So editbin has problems using file names containing a path. Dang.

Comment: But still it does not work as post build step. Strange.

Comment: @Sam: Last thing which comes to mind is, that if you have an implicit path, that the working directory could be wrong.

Comment: The post build step normally executes from the solution directory not the output directory - you should use `"$(TargetPath)"` instead of `app.exe` (make sure you surround the path with quotes).

Comment: @Kragen, $(TargetPath) does not work since Editbin can't handle path names. Editbin can for some reason only handle files in the working directory.

Comment: @Sam Ah - in that case have your post-build step `cd` to the output directory before executing `editbin`.

Comment: @Sam are you sure that it doesn't work - even if you put quotes around the path?

Comment: @Kragen, I tried it manually in a command line, using a path without spaces or other strange symbols, and it did not work.
Does this work for you??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This shouldn't work, odd that you don't get a build error.  The path isn't set correctly to be able to use the tool in a C# build.  It does work from the command line, the Visual Studio Command Prompt uses the config for a C/C++ project.  This post-build command worked properly in VS2008:

```
set path=%path%;$(DevEnvDir);$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\bin
editbin.exe /STACK:2097152 "$(TargetPath)"
```

Also note the double-quotes around the target path macro to deal with spaces.

Comment: Aah, yes, the search path was the problem!! I added the path to \vc\bin, but the other one was still missing, so it did neither work nor put out an error.

Comment: I believe it's slightly more robust to begin your post-build step with `call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"` . That's what I do.

Answer (score -1):

Does this help? [/F (Set Stack Size)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28vs.71%29.aspx)

This is basically providing the /F switch along with the number of bytes you want to reserve for stack.

Comment: This is what I need, but where would I put this for a c# program?

Comment: This option is for the C++ compiler, not the C# compiler.

Comment: Yep - And since my program is a c# program, the option cannot be set for it.