# What's the .NET equivalent of link.exe's /RELEASE switch?

Tags: c#, .net

When linking a native image, you specify /RELEASE so that link.exe stamps a checksum on the binary, so windbg doesn't complain about

```
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for foo.exe
```

How do I do that for a .NET program? I've looked at the options in CSC.EXE, AL.EXE, but can't find anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [editbin.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst6zb25%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in a post-build event to achieve the same.  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538477/stack-overflow-in-c-sharp-app-using-c-dll/5546869#5546869) for an example event, use /RELEASE instead.

It is only required for device drivers, so this doesn't matter for managed code.

Comment: Actually, I think device drivers need a lot more than a valid checksum in the header. They need to be signed. I'm mostly concerned about cleanliness of my binary -- and don't want the debugger spewing this every time. Editbin is a reasonable workaround. Thanks!