# Is it possible to run a .NET 4.5 app on XP?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, compatibility, .net-4.5

First, I have read the following:

- [Connect case](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730732/net-framework-4-5-should-support-windows-xp-sp3)
- [VS case](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2723735-make-net-4-5-work-on-any-os-that-supports-4-0)
- and especially [this channel9 post](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Why-is-XP-Support-for-NET-45-not-happening)

So, from the last bullet, I really think there is no way around this, but I had to see if I could get a definitive answer as my team would like to upgrade from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5. However, we have to support XP.

**Is there no possibility of going to .NET 4.5 if we want to support XP?**

The only thing I could think of is creating two separate solutions, but then the codebases would have to diverge if we used .NET 4.5 features.

So, I am looking for some amazing workaround that I could not find and others maybe already know.

Comment: No, you can't. Stick to 4.0 until XP dies definitely.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

I hesitate to post this answer, it is actually technically possible but it doesn't work that well in practice.  The version numbers of the CLR and the core framework assemblies were not changed in 4.5.  You still target v4.0.30319 of the CLR and the framework assembly version numbers are still 4.0.0.0.  The only thing that's distinctive about the assembly manifest when you look at it with a disassembler like ildasm.exe is the presence of a  [TargetFramework] attribute that says that 4.5 is needed, that would have to be altered.  Not actually that easy, it is emitted by the compiler.

The biggest difference is not that visible, Microsoft made a long-overdue change in the executable header of the assemblies.  Which specifies what version of Windows the executable is compatible with.  XP belongs to a previous generation of Windows, started with Windows 2000.  Their major version number is 5.  Vista was the start of the current generation, major version number 6.

.NET compilers have always specified the minimum version number to be 4.00, the version of Windows NT and Windows 9x.  You can see this by running dumpbin.exe /headers on the assembly.  Sample output looks like this:

```
OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
            ...
            4.00 operating system version
            0.00 image version
            4.00 subsystem version              // <=== here!!
               0 Win32 version
            ...
```

What's new in .NET 4.5 is that the compilers change that subsystem version to 6.00.  A change that was over-due in large part because Windows pays attention to that number, beyond just checking if it is small enough.  It also turns on appcompat features since it assumes that the program was written to work on old versions of Windows.  These features cause trouble, particularly the way Windows lies about the size of a window in Aero is troublesome.  It stops lying about the fat borders of an Aero window when it can see that the program was designed to run on a Windows version that has Aero.

You can alter that version number and set it back to 4.00 by running Editbin.exe on your assemblies with the /subsystem option.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546869/17034) shows a sample postbuild event.

That's however about where the good news ends, a significant problem is that .NET 4.5 isn't very compatible with .NET 4.0.  By far the biggest hang-up is that classes were moved from one assembly to another.  Most notably, that happened for the [Extension] attribute.  Previously in System.Core.dll, it got moved to Mscorlib.dll in .NET 4.5.  That's a kaboom on XP if you declare your own extension methods, your program says to look in Mscorlib for the attribute, enabled by a [TypeForwardedTo] attribute in the .NET 4.5 version of the System.Core reference assembly.  But it isn't there when you run your program on .NET 4.0

And of course there's nothing that helps you stop using classes and methods that are only available on .NET 4.5.  When you do, your program will fail with a TypeLoadException or MissingMethodException when run on 4.0

Just target 4.0 and all of these problems disappear.  Or break that logjam and stop supporting XP, a business decision that programmers cannot often make but can certainly encourage by pointing out the hassles that it is causing.  There is of course a non-zero cost to having to support ancient operating systems, just the testing effort is substantial.  A cost that isn't often recognized by management, Windows compatibility is legendary, unless it is pointed out to them.  Forward that cost to the client and they tend to make the right decision a lot quicker :)  But we can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I figured there were some breaking changes. I appreciate the workaround, too. We cannot go with it for the reasons you specified, but it is good to know. Maybe XP will go away for good someday....

Comment: `just the testing effort is substantial` - thats what got our managment to "allow to drop XP support".

Comment: I know this is an old posting - but - @JustinPihony : Has your company ever thought of installing a later OS and then installing VMWare or Virtual Box? It is a bit late for Windows 7 - but Microsoft gave away a virtual Windows XP install that allowed you to toggle between 7 & XP.  Just a thought. :-)

Comment: @MarkManning it wasn't in our control. It was being used elsewhere.

Comment: @JustinPihony: Ah. Hmmmmm......  My only other suggestion is a kluge. Capture the OS version and then just set up all of the functions in your classes to be put into arrays (or an array). Have one array (or part of an array) be for XP and the other for newer OSs. Then all you need is some kind of global variable that is used to denote which set to use. The calls could all be the same (or look the same) but one set uses NET40_<FUNCTION> and the others could use NET45_<FUNCTION>. This would be an indirect call to the function itself. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 21):

[Sadly, no, you can't run 4.5 programs on XP.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730732/net-framework-4-5-should-support-windows-xp-sp3,)

And the relevant post from that Connect page:

> Posted by Microsoft on 23/03/2012 at 10:39
>   Thanks for the report. This behavior is by design in .NET Framework 4.5 Beta. The minimum supported operating systems are Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 SP2 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. Windows XP is not a supported operating system for the Beta release.

Answer (score 8):

The Mono project dropped Windows XP support and *"forgot"* to mention it. Although they still claim Windows XP SP2 is the minimum supported version, it is actually Windows Vista.

The last version of Mono to support Windows XP was 3.2.3.

Answer (score 7):

Try mono:

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

This download works on all versions of Windows XP, 2003, Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Mono is slower than .NET, and while it has most features of .NET 4.5, it lacks certain major components like WPF (http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility). So you can use Mono for XP support if it provides all that you need, and you are okay with the performance implications. On the plus side, there should be no need to create a special "Mono build", the normal .NET 4.5 build typically works under Mono, but you need to test against Mono specifically to ensure you're compatible.

Comment: I've tried mono-3.12.1-gtksharp-2.12.26-win32-0.msi under Windows XP SP3 and it failed with *"mono.exe is not a valid Win32 application"*. I've also tried mono-3.0.10-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe which failed with *"mono.exe - Entry Point Not Found. The procedure entry point InterlockedCompareExchange64 could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll"*.

Answer (score 4):

Last version to support windows XP (SP3) is mono-4.3.2.467-gtksharp-2.12.30.1-win32-0.msi and that doesnot replace .NET 4.5 but could be of interest for some applications.

see there:
https://download.mono-project.com/archive/4.3.2/windows-installer/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible you need to install one core api: github.com/Skulltrail192/One-Core-API-Binaries the you can install .NET up to 4.8