# How to run .Net 4.5 application on windows XP

Tags: c#, windows-xp

How can I run a .Net 4.5 application on windows XP?
does it requires a specific edition of XP (SP1, SP2 or SP3)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy but xp doesn't support .Net4.5. So answer is **no** you can't. Even if you manage to do there is no guarantee that it will work properly

Comment: You must install .net 4.5. Here is post on if and how to do it '[Is it possible to run a .net 4.5 app on XP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499351/is-it-possible-to-run-a-net-4-5-app-on-xp)'

Comment: I think it is a valid question as it refers to which SP to use

Comment: @RamiHelmy I think suggested duplicate is also valid since whichever SP you use doesn't matter when msft don't support it officially

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, no objection. let's wait for the votes.

Comment: Yes, it is possible you need to install one core api: https://github.com/Skulltrail192/One-Core-API-Binaries the you can install .NET up to 4.8

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. You need to install .Net 4.5, but this is [not supported for XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line; It is possible to install and run .NET 4.5 on Windows XP (Service Pack 3) but it is not officially supported and your app will probably experience some problems.

The system requirements for installing .NET Framework 4.5 is listed here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30653

As you can see Windows XP is not listed as a compatible OS

Check that support ticket too.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730732/net-framework-4-5-should-support-windows-xp-sp3

and the answer to that question too:

[Is it possible to run a .NET 4.5 app on XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499351/is-it-possible-to-run-a-net-4-5-app-on-xp)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a .NET 4.5 Application on that obsolete system.

You need the .NET Framework 4.5 which has the following system requirements:

**Supported Operating System**

- Windows 7 Service Pack 1
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
- Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2
- Windows Vista Service Pack 2 Windows Vista SP2 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64) Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 (x86 and x64)

**Hardware Requirements:**

- 1 GHz or faster processor
- 512 MB of RAM
- 850 MB of available hard disk space (x86)
- 2 GB hard drive (x64)

**XP is not listed.**