# How to allow my VB.net program to run on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, windows-xp

I was wondering if it is possible to allow my program to run in Windows XP using VB.net. Every other time I tried it comes up with a error that says: "This is not a Win32 Application"
I found where the Windows Settings for the applications are, but I cannot seem to understand what XP's supportedOS Id is. According to the settings it says
`<!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->`

And then it list versions of Windows with the supportedOS Id.

I also found a section at the end that says: `<!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->`
Is there a way I can add Windows XP to this list?

Comment: what version of the .net framework are you using?  is the .net framework installed on the xp computer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499351/is-it-possible-to-run-a-net-4-5-app-on-xp

Comment: @KenTucker I am using version 4.5.1 and should that be preinstalled on XP SP3?

Comment: That sounds right. I suppose, another option might be to change your app to an earlier version of the framework and try that.

Comment: i think the only supported version of the .net framework that runs on xp is .net 3.5

Comment: @GreenApplications : .NET 4.5.1 **is definitely not** pre-installed on XP machines. Windows XP is far older than .NET 4.5.1. For comparison: .NET 4.5.1 was released in October 2013, and Windows XP was officially **deprecated** in April 2014 (12 years after its release). The highest .NET version you'll find **pre-installed** on an XP machine is .NET 1.0, however you might still be able to install some of the newer versions (though .NET 4.0 is the only one that is **officially** supported).

Comment: @KenTucker : Actually .NET 4.0 is also officially supported on Windows XP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run a .NET 4.5 app on XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499351/is-it-possible-to-run-a-net-4-5-app-on-xp)

Comment: Googling your error message suggests that this can arise when trying to run a 64-bit program on a 32 bit OS.

Comment: @peterG My application is a 32-bit application, but it can run on x64 computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to change the framework to 4.0 Client Profile, or 4.0 Full, in order to get my applications to work on Windows XP. Thanks to all those who helped!